# Getting tidy output from post hoc tests

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, tidyeval, tukey

Consider this data frame `dat1`:

```r
dat1 <- data.frame(Region = rep(c("r1","r2"), each = 100),
                   State = rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 10),
                   Loc = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),each = 5),
                   ID = rep(c(1:10), each=2),
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var2 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200))
```

I have data frames that are similar to `dat1` created above. `Region`,`State`,and `Loc` are grouping variables for each observation `ID`, and 5 measurements are taken upon each observation `var1:var5`. For each grouping variable, I am conducting univariate anovas on each `var`. When significant differences are found, I am using the `TukeyHSD()` function and the `multcompLetters()` function from the `multcompView` package to generate CLD's on the groups. Since I want to do this for each grouping variable I am trying to write a function to keep myself from being repetitive and making typos. Below shows where I am with this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(multcomp)
library(multcompView)

Tuk <- function(dat,groupvar,var){
  TUK <- TukeyHSD(aov(lm(get(var) ~ get(groupvar), data=dat)))
  names(TUK)[[1]] <- paste0(groupvar)
  lets<-multcompLetters(extract_p(TUK$groupvar))
  lets
}
#assuming all 5 vars were significant in the anovas, I would then run this for each grouping variable as follows:
vars <- paste0(names(dat1[,5:9]))
#by Region
lapply(vars, FUN=Tuk, dat=dat1, groupvar="Region")
#by State
lapply(vars, FUN=Tuk, dat=dat1, groupvar="State")
#by Loc
lapply(vars, FUN=Tuk, dat=dat1, groupvar="Loc")
```

The code works outside of the function. The function will create the model, but I cant figure out how to format it so that it recognizes what `groupvar` is for the `multcompLetters(extract_p())` part? How can I fix this, and how can I get it the function to output a tidy table that shows each group and the letters for each variable I give it at once. For example it would look something like this for `State` using all 5 variables

```r
     NY   MA   FL   GA
var1  a    ab   c    a
var2  a    ab   b    c
var3  a    c    ab   bc  
var4  ab   c    ab   ab 
var5  a    b    c     b
```

Also, is there a reasonable way to make this function produce boxplots (for each variable) of the groups that show the CLD letters?

Comment: To make the function work replace `TUK$groupvar` with `TUK[[groupvar]]`.

Comment: Are your questions related?  Is the goal to produce boxplots and label the differences in p.values?

Comment: @Chuck P yes I would like for the function to ultimately produce boxplots and label the differences in p.values. @stefan's solution to the `groupvar` issue worked, I was still hoping to get assistance with using this to produce plots

Comment: Hmmmm, let me show you an existing packagae that will do what I think you want before we invest time in rolling your own.  I'm not very familiar with `multcompLetters` but very familar with plotting and charting oneway AOV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the plot is truly what you're looking for does this get you pretty close for a sing plot of var1 ~ State, Indrajeet has done a great job of building this package and I hate reinventing wheels.

```r
dat1 <- data.frame(Region = rep(c("r1","r2"), each = 100),
                   State = rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 10),
                   Loc = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),each = 5),
                   ID = rep(c(1:10), each=2),
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var2 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200))

library(ggstatsplot)

ggbetweenstats(dat1, State, var1, 
               plot.type = "box", 
               pairwise.comparisons = TRUE, 
               pairwise.display = "everything")

#> Note: Shapiro-Wilk Normality Test for var1: p-value = 0.183
#> 
#> Note: Bartlett's test for homogeneity of variances for factor State: p-value = 0.373
#>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You accepted the answer but just documenting you can get what you originally asked with a little work...

```r
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050403/getting-tidy-output-from-post-hoc-tests/62052651#62052651

library(multcompView)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyselect)

set.seed(1111)
dat1 <- data.frame(Region = rep(c("r1","r2"), each = 100),
                   State = rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 10),
                   Loc = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),each = 5),
                   ID = rep(c(1:10), each = 2),
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var2 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200))

# You want just the letters which you can get by ...
multcompLetters(TukeyHSD(aov(var1  ~ State, data = dat1))$State[,4])$Letters
#>  GA  MA  NY  FL 
#> "a" "a" "a" "a"

# Your function redone...
Tuk3 <- function(data,
                 groupvar,
                 var) {
  lst <- as.list(match.call())
  if (is.symbol(lst$groupvar) || is.symbol(lst$var)) {
    stop("Please quote all variables")
  }
  if (!is.call(groupvar)) {
    grouplabel <- rlang::as_name(rlang::enquo(groupvar))
  }

  data <-
    dplyr::select(
      .data = data,
      var = {{ var }},
      groupvar = {{ groupvar }}
    )

  aov_object <- aov(var ~ groupvar, data = data)
  aov_results <- broom::tidy(aov_object) %>%
    mutate(term = if_else(term != "Residuals", grouplabel, term))
  tukey_results <- broom::tidy(TukeyHSD(aov_object)) %>%
    mutate(term = grouplabel)

  # multcompLetters is annoying and wants named vectors
  p_values <- tukey_results %>% pull(adj.p.value)
  names(p_values) <- tukey_results %>% pull(comparison)
  letters_results <-  data.frame(as.list(multcompLetters(p_values)$Letters))
  return(letters_results)
}

# works for one
Tuk3(data = dat1, groupvar = "State", var = "var1")
#>   GA MA NY FL
#> 1  a  a  a  a

# you could do this manually but I do it a lot so I have a function
variables_list <- CGPfunctions::cross2_var_vectors(dat1, 1:3, 5:9)

# Make the names nice
outcomes2 <- variables_list$lista
groupings2 <- variables_list$listb
names(groupings2) <- unlist(groupings2)
names(outcomes2) <- paste(unlist(outcomes2), "~", unlist(groupings2))

# get all 15 results and a final map_dfr to make one tibble
map2(.x = outcomes2,
     .y = groupings2,
     .f = ~ Tuk3(dat = dat1,
                 var = tidyselect::all_of(.x),
                 groupvar = tidyselect::all_of(.y))) %>% 
       map_dfr(~ rbind(.), .id = "Which_ANOVA")
#>      Which_ANOVA   r2   r1   GA   MA   NY   FL    b    c    d    e    f    g
#> 1  var1 ~ Region    a    a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 2  var2 ~ Region    a    a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 3  var3 ~ Region    a    a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 4  var4 ~ Region    a    a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 5  var5 ~ Region    a    a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 6   var1 ~ State <NA> <NA>    a    a    a    a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 7   var2 ~ State <NA> <NA>    a    a    a    a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 8   var3 ~ State <NA> <NA>    a    a    a    a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 9   var4 ~ State <NA> <NA>    a    a    a    a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 10  var5 ~ State <NA> <NA>    a    b   ab   ab <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 11    var1 ~ Loc <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    a    a    a    a    a    a
#> 12    var2 ~ Loc <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    a    a    a    a    a    a
#> 13    var3 ~ Loc <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    a    a    a    a    a    a
#> 14    var4 ~ Loc <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    a    a    a    a    a    a
#> 15    var5 ~ Loc <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   ab   ab   ab    a   ab    b
```

I cut off the results

Comment: This looks very promising. Unfortunately, when I try this with my data, I get the error message "Please quote all variables". I'm not sure why this happens as I don't understand this part of the code. Could you maybe explain when the error message appears?

Comment: The error message will show up if the variables list you are passing to the function has bare variable names rather than being passed as strings.  So make sure that whatever you are using as `outcomes2` and `groupings2` are strings